# WF 4.0: Tracking notifications when a WorkflowApplication stops being Idle?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am interested in timing arbitrary WorkflowApplication instances to see how long they spend "busy" and how long idle.

However, it seems that tracking notifications are only generated when the instance becomes Idle, and not when it is reactivated.

Is there an easy way of getting such a notification?

UPDATE:

```
        WorkflowApplication wa = new WorkflowApplication(activity);

        var tracker = new ConsoleTrackingParticipant()
        {
            TrackingProfile = new TrackingProfile
            {
                Name = "SampleTrackingProfile",
                ImplementationVisibility = ImplementationVisibility.All                    
            }
        };


        var query = new WorkflowInstanceQuery();
        query.States.Add("*");
        tracker.TrackingProfile.Queries.Add(query);

        var brq = new BookmarkResumptionQuery()
        {
            Name = "*"
        };

        tracker.TrackingProfile.Queries.Add(brq);

        wa.Extensions.Add(tracker);

        wa.Run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost every case a workflow goes idle because of a bookmark being created. And for the workflow to continue the bookmark must be resumed. With a [TrackingParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingparticipant.aspx) you can receive a [BookmarkResumptionRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.bookmarkresumptionrecord) when this happens. In order to receive these you will need to configure a [TrackingProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513989) and add a [BookmarkResumptionQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.bookmarkresumptionquery).

Comment: Hi Maurice, thanks for the answer. My workflows usually go idle due to AsyncCodeActivity, but I see this is implemented using bookmarks. I tried adding a BookmarkResumptionQuery to my tracking profile, but it complains about the name being null if I don't set it, yet I don't have the name handy. Is there a way to query for all bookmark resumptions? I tried looking on MSDN and google, but there's not much info about how to use this.

Comment: Further info: the AsyncCodeActivity uses an unnamed bookmark which is internal to the framework. I tried running a query with the name = String.Empty, but this does not raise any notifications.

Comment: Try setting the name to "*". This should match all bookmarks.

Comment: With an AsyncCodeActivity the alternative would be to use a pair of CustomTrackingRecord's in the BeginExecute and EndExecute methods.

Comment: I've looked at the code further in a reflector, and you are right about name = "*" but for some reason it never triggers. I also notice that there is a WorkflowInstanceRecord state of "Resumed", but this also never fires (even though I get "Started", "Idle" and "Completed" coming through fine). Very strange, will investigate further.

Comment: I don't think AsyncCodeActivity uses bookmarks internally as it uses IAsyncResult. You can either use a ActivityStateQuery but that will tell you when it is done, not when the EndExecute() resumed. A better solution would be to use a CustomTrackingRecord.

Comment: Thanks Maurice, I have decided to go with the custom tracking record idea, and a subclass of AsyncCodeActivity. It is actually better for me to track individual activities being idle/resumed than the whole workflow anyway. (PS it does use bookmarks internally, but doesn't raise the notifications oddly).